# Stylesheets inclusion in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, directive, scss-mixins

I am trying to incorporate bootstrap 4 into my Rails 5.2 project. Currently, my app/stylesheets/application.css, has the following in it:

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
*/
```

The instructions, in addition to renaming it application.scss, call for deleting:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

And adding:

```
@import 'bootstrap'
```

Isn't "require_tree ." needed to include all the stylesheets in the stylesheets folder? and the "require_self", to include any styles I may decide to add in the application.scss file?

So if I remove these two statements, would I need to include every single stylesheet individually, using an @import statement. For instance, if I have: user.scss, I would add:

```
@import 'user'
```

I've seen some examples where the require_tree and require_self are kept. Your advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use asterisk to path like

```
 @import "path/to/*"
```

if you add all sxss in 'stylesheet' path (ex: stylesheet/a.sxss, b.sxss)

```
 @import "*"
```

else you add all sxss in 'stylesheet/page' path (ex: stylesheet/page/a.sxss, b.sxss)

```
@import "page/*"
```

Comment: My IDE doesn't seem to like it (Rubymine). It's flagging it red, with this message: Cannot resolve file '\*'

Comment: Cannot resolve directory 'path', cannot resolve directory 'to', cannot resolve file '*'

Comment: path to is just expression.